# One GPIO pin for LED, Pushbutton and Buzzer via high-pass filter?

Tags: led, gpio, button, piezo-buzzer

There's [Pin as both input (for a switch) and output (for LED) with ATmega32U4?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/264208/124114) but I also need one of six such pins to drive a piezo buzzer.
Due to its capacitive nature, I figured it could be connected to the GPIO as well (has no effect on DC signals):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fff01V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea was to suppress the noise, that would likely originate from switching the GPIO from output-low (to drive the LED) to input-pull-up (for sampling the pushbutton), using a high pass filter with an "odd" 1.5 kHz or so, so sampling at 100 Hz or so does not affect the 4 kHz piezo as much.

Drawbacks (both are acceptable):

- pushing the button lights the LED (and dumps C1's charge to ground; maybe add a series resistor?)
- driving the piezo with a 4 kHz square wave lights the LED at 50 % (maybe this can be a lower duty-cycle due to the filter?)

Does this work and can it be improved?

Comment: how fast do you need the LED to turn on or off?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's just a status LED for humans: visible frequency for blinking would be in the 1 Hz range, so the transition should not take longer than maybe 0.1 s.

Comment: See [LED and Button Matrix multiplexing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361149) for a different approach to possibly work around too few pins in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course, instead of directly driving the LED, add a high-impedance low pass filter, driving a thresholding element (e.g. a transistor, a comparator with a reference, or an elegantly connected diode), which in turn drives the LED.

```
                                     +3.3V
                                       |
                                       R
                                       |
                                      LED
     +----High Pass----Piezo---GND     |
GPIO-+----------------Switch---GND   |/
     +----R_large---+----------------| 
                    |                |\
                    C                  v
                    |                  |
                   GND                GND
```