# LED and Button Matrix multiplexing?

Tags: led, multiplexer, button, matrix

I have only six GPIO to control a piezo buzzer and 6 LEDs and read 6 buttons...
Would multiplexing the 6 LEDs/buttons in a 2x3 matrix work like this (i.e. 5 pins for the 6 LEDs and buttons, one dedicated pin for the buzzer):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fopp9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Driving the LEDs with "regular" multiplexing, i.e. row as output high, column as output low.
Scanning the buttons by setting row as output high and column to input with pull-down.

Drawback: pushing the button causes the LED to go off, increasing current - not be a problem with low-current LEDs.

Am I missing something? Could it be improved? Are there any implementations "out there"?

Comment: Duplicate question from a few minutes ago?

Comment: @AlmostDone Same original problem, but different approach, so no.

Comment: That question is: [One GPIO pin for LED, Pushbutton and Buzzer via high-pass filter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361144/)

Answer (score 2):

> Scanning the buttons by setting row as output high and column to input
>   with pull-down.

The LEDs would still be forward biased and could be recognized as if a button was being pressed. It's borderline that this will work effectively.

When driving the LEDs, keep the row as a driver and the column as an input (with a pull down) but, when scanning the switches, reverse bias the LEDs by driving the column high and having a 10k to 100k pull down on the rows (now set as inputs): -

You could even put a diode in series with the switches to stop the LED being "blanked" when the switch is pressed. Clearly when scanning the switches the LED gets turned off for a small length of time but this should be unnoticeable if scanning switches / driving LEDs at a fast rate.

[image]

It should work at logic levels as low as 3.3 volts but check the input threshold high limits in the data sheet are not greater than about 2.6 volts.